# Font-Awesome-Rails CSS spinner not working in Safari

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, font-awesome

I'm using the `font-awesome-rails` gem to show a css spinner when the submit button of a `form_for` is clicked. The spinner works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't appear in Safari. I'm on OSX El Capitan 10.11.15 and hosting on Heroku. I'm also using Bootstrap 3.

My submit button looks like this:

```
<%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-default", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving Changes..."} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your html is generated uncorrectly and there is nothing to do with Safari

```
<%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-default", 'data-disable-with' => "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving Changes...".html_safe %>
```